# Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxxx bytes) in /.../bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Tags: git, laravel, macos, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have seen very much questions about this issue , unfortunately, none of the solutions of how to fix it did not help me. So, I am trying to run `php artisan key:generate` in my terminal with composer, but as long as I am trying, it shows that `Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted...`.
What should I do? I have already changed my PHP memory limit to 32MB and I guess, it should work, but it doesn't. Also, perhaps I should re-write something on autoload.php file?

Thanks for future answers

Comment: Why do you use so little memory? Try to use at least 128Mb.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Recently, I expanded it to 128MB - still the error is the same..

Comment: Is it a fresh install?

Comment: Are you sure you edit the right `php.ini`? I mean the one for cli, not for fpm.

Comment: Hmm, how to know this? Cause when I check where is my Loaded Configuration File (so.. `php.ini`) it shows dir of /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/conf/ and I have changed `php.ini` file from here..

Comment: Have you modified any of the service providers?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter no, I haven't

Comment: You should put a `.php` file containing `<?php phpinfo();`, do a HTTP GET request to an URL mapping to that file and study the information sheet generated—it will tell you from where exactly your PHP interpreter grabs its settings. The problem is that there are oh so many ways to run interpret PHP scripts, and they differ in where their settings are located, and there are hierarchies of them and… oh, well…

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 artisan key:generate
```

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.